# Вывод некоторых характеристик в bitrix на странице товара

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

На странице товара в bitrix есть блок с некоторыми характеристиками (выделен красным), выбранными из основной кучи. По какому признаку в базе данных я могу найти их прямо в базе и в какой таблице? Спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какова цель искать сразу в БД? Использовать АПИ не учили? Все свойства можно получить не залезая в таблицы напрямую.

Comment: bitrix не знаю совсем, мне надо сделать оттуда импорт в другую систему, проще всего напрямую из базы взять чтобы не копаться в премудростях битрикса

Comment: Свойства будут в таблице b_iblock_properties.

Comment: а признак по которому выбираются выделенные 7 свойств?

Comment: Нужно смотреть по таблицам b_iblock* одной таблицей вы вряд-ли обойдетесь. Нужно искать идентификаторы и составлять запрос.

Comment: судя по активности битриксом никто не заниается ((

Comment: Ваш запрос довольно редкий. Если нужны такие выгрузки, то их гораздо легче формировать отдельно изнутри системы встроенными методами.

Comment: Битрикс умеет делать выгрузку информации о товарах в форматах csv и xml. Это делается в разделе "Контент"-"Инфоблоки"-"Экспорт". Можете выгрузить всю информацию о товарах которая вам нужно.

Comment: у меня есть только дамп базы из которого мне нужно вручную сделать импорт в другую систему. Самого битрикса нет, и разбираться в нем если честно совсем не хочется. Я уже всё вывел в импорт кроме описанного момента. меня просто удивляют ответы. ведь вопрос конкретный, нопочему то все отвечают не по существу. такое ощущение что никто не знает как это устроено))) Ведь какимто образом битрикс выцепляет эти 7 свойств из общей кучи. Так по какому признаку?!! этот признак в базе или вне базы? ...битрикс как то это делает значит и я должет смочь сделать то же самое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ:
данные свойства никак в таблицах битрикса не помечены, а тупо выводятся первые по количеству  указанному в $arParams["COUNT_PROPERTIES"] в файле шаблона. вот его код:

```
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die(); ?>
<?$this->setFrameMode(true);?>
<?$propertyCounter=0;?>
<?if(!empty($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"])):?>
    <div class="elementProperties">
        <div class="headingBox">
            <div class="heading">
                <?=GetMessage("CATALOG_ELEMENT_CHARACTERISTICS_SHORT");?>
            </div>
            <div class="moreProperties">
                <a href="#" class="morePropertiesLink"><?=GetMessage("CATALOG_ELEMENT_MORE_PROPERTIES")?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="propertyList">
            <?foreach ($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $ip => $arProperty):?>
                <?if(!empty($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]) && ++$propertyCounter <= $arParams["COUNT_PROPERTIES"]):?>
                    <?if(gettype($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]) == "array"){
                        $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"] = implode(" / ", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);
                    }?>
                    <div class="propertyTable">
                        <div class="propertyName"><?=preg_replace("/\[.*\]/", "", $arProperty["NAME"])?></div>
                        <div class="propertyValue">
                            <?if($arProperty["PROPERTY_TYPE"] == "E" || $arProperty["PROPERTY_TYPE"] == "S"):?>
                                <?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]?>
                            <?else:?>
                                <?if($arProperty["FILTRABLE"] =="Y" && !empty($arProperty["VALUE_ENUM_ID"]) && $arProperty["FROM_SKU"] != "Y" && !empty($arResult["LAST_SECTION"])):?>
                                    <a href="<?=$arResult["LAST_SECTION"]["SECTION_PAGE_URL"]?>?arrFilter_<?=$arProperty["ID"]?>_<?=abs(crc32($arProperty["VALUE_ENUM_ID"]))?>=Y&amp;set_filter=Y" class="analog">
                                <?endif;?><?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]?>
                                <?if($arProperty["FILTRABLE"] == "Y" && !empty($arProperty["VALUE_ENUM_ID"]) && $arProperty["FROM_SKU"] != "Y"):?>
                                    </a>
                                <?endif;?>
                            <?endif;?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?endif;?>
            <?endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Значения свойств элементов инфоблока хранятся в таблице `b_iblock_element_property`.
В поле `IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID` хранится `ID` свойства инфоблока имя которого вы можете узнать в таблице `b_iblock_iproperty` (ну или наоборот по имени получите `ID`).

Поле `IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID` хранит `ID` элемента инфоблока (ид товара) в системе из таблицы `b_iblock_element`.